# Why is Aws::VERSION an uninitialized constant in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, paperclip, aws-sdk

From my research, I suspect this is a versioning issue, and I need some help making a monkey patch, but I could be totally wrong.

I'm attaching avatars to users with `Paperclip` I recently updated both `Paperclip` and `aws-sdk` and now I'm getting the error:

```
uninitialized constant Aws::VERSION
```

My gem file has:

```
gem "paperclip", "~> 5.1.0"
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 3.0.1'
```

Could someone explain what happened in these updates that made this no longer work? I've never had to look into my gems before so I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have issues with:

paperclip (5.2.1)
aws-sdk (2.10.47)

In case it help others.